# Docker container to container connect: connection refused

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

When all are run standalone outside of docker it works with no problem when core attempts to do a get from cerner. However, doing the same when all are dockerized as below I get:

Get http://cerner:8602/api/v1/patient/search: dial TCP 192.168.240.4:8602: connect: connection refused.  The .4 is the IP of the cerner container and .2 is the IP of the core container

Cerner is the name of the container being called from core. If I change the name to the ip-address of the host server and use the ports, it works fine also.  It just does not allow container to container using the containers DNS or IP. I have attempted with and without the private network and get the same thing.

The containers are all scratch go.

```
version: '3.7'

services:    caConnector:
      image: vertisoft/ca_connector:latest
      ports:
        - "8601:7001"
      env_file:
        - .env.ca_connector
      networks:
        - core-net

   fhir:
      image: vertisoft/fhir_connector:latest
      container_name: cerner
      ports:
        - "8602:7002"
      env_file:
        - .env.fhir_connector
      networks:
        - core-net

   core:
      image: vertisoft/core:latest
      ports:
        - "8600:7000"
      env_file:
        - .env.core
      networks:
        - core-net

networks:   core-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: The service name is `fhir`. You should be able to connect it using `fhir`, not `cerner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the container service with `containerPort`, not with hostPort in service to service communication. in your case, it should be `7000 to 7002` for any container to connect using container name.

> Get http://cerner:8602/api/v1/patient/search: dial TCP
>   192.168.240.4:8602: connect: connection refused.

As in the error, it tries to attempt connection using publish port.

For example

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

When you run docker-compose up, the following happens:

> A network called myapp_default is created.
>
> A container is created
>   using web’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under
>   the name web. A container is created using db’s configuration. It
>   joins the network myapp_default under the name db.
>
> In v2.1+, overlay
>   networks are always attachable
>
> Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the
>   appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application
>   code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432 and start using the
>   Postgres database.

It is important to note the distinction **between HOST_PORT and CONTAINER_PORT**. In the above example, for db, the **HOST_PORT** is `8001` and the **container port** is `5432` (postgres default). Networked **service-to-service** communication use the **CONTAINER_PORT**. When HOST_PORT is defined, the service is accessible outside the swarm as well.

Within the web container, your connection string to db would look like `postgres://db:5432`, and from the host machine, the connection string would look like `postgres://{DOCKER_IP}:8001`.

[compose-networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: in your answer, could you use the OPs example? the one you use is more confusing since you have two 8000 ports. also `postgres://{DOCKER_IP}:8001` why does this reference the image name? Thank you!

Comment: @AustinL when you want to access Postgres container from outside of container network or from host machine you should use `8001` with because it the publish port that will see the outer world, while `5432` is only visible in container network.